# Can't limit to only 3 or 4 days in week/week view in React big calendar

Tags: reactjs, next.js, calendar, react-big-calendar

I am trying to implement a calendar on my website which has visible with 3 or 4 days in week / week view for our customers. How can I implement this week view with 3 or 4 days? Are there any properties provided by React Big Calendar?

I have searched for props but could not find. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.